# What does Padma Purana I.43.128b-133b say?

Tags: women, identification-request, padma-purana

What does Padma Purana I.43.128b-133b say? Does it say the following:

> Joining her lotus-like hands and concealing her face the beloved of the Mountain saluted the sage, a heap of lustre…Then the respectable daughter of the Himalaya mountain, whose mind was amazed, saw the sage Narada of wonderful form. The sage also addressed her with (these) affectionate words: ‘Come, O daughter’. But embracing the father, she sat on his lap. The mother said to the respectable girl: ‘O daughter, salute the revered sage, blessed with penance. (Thereby) you will obtain a husband of your liking’. Thus addressed by her mother, she, having covered her face with her garment and with her slightly trembling, did not utter any word.

Is the above English translation of the verse correct?

Comment: can you be more clear? It describes Goddess Parvati marriage with Shiva.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Its tough to be clearer. Could you tell me exactly what the verse says?

Comment: Can you at least add the verse?

Comment: @NogShine Um ok but don't ask me where I got please.

Comment: What did you wanted to know? This is all unclear. You had the verses with English translation. Then what is your exact question?

Comment: @NogShine Actually I was checking whether the verses I have are correct. Because they were quoted from an unreliable source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Verses 128b - 133b of Chapter 43, Sristi Khanda, Padma Purana*  describes conversation of Narada with Himavat, Mena and Goddess Parvati and Indra was also present with them. When Narada was talking to Himavata, Mena and Parvati enters the room. (translated by Dr. N.A Deshpande and Sanskrit manuscript is Venkateswara Edition).

> 126-128a. When the divine sage was speaking these words with respect,
>   Mena, the queen of Mountain Himalaya, who was followed by her
>   daughter, who had a few friends and attendants (with her), and who was
>   humble due to bashfulness and courtesy, entered, with a desire to see
>   the sage, the house, where the best and restrained sage was staying
>   with the Mountain.
>
> 128b-129a. Joining her lotus-like hands and concealing her face the
>   beloved of the Mountain saluted the sage, a heap of lustre.
>
> 129b-130a. The divine sage, of matchless lustre, having seen the
>   magnanimous lady, congratulated her with blessings resembling the
>   stream of nectar.
>
> 130b-131a. Then the respectable daughter of the Himalaya mountain,
>   whose mind was amazed, saw the sage Narada of a wonderful form.
>
> 131b-133a. The sage also addressed her with (these) affectionate
>   words: "Come, O daughter". But embracing the father, she sat on his
>   lap. The mother said to the respectable girl: "O daughter, salute the
>   revered sage, blessed with penance. (Thereby) you will obtain a
>   husband of your liking".
>
> 133b-135. Thus addressed by her mother, she, having covered her face
>   with her garment and with her head slightly trembling, did not utter
>   any word. Then the mother again said these words to her daughter: "O
>   daughter, salute the divine sage. I shall give you a fine jewelled
>   toy, which I have kept (aside) fora longtime."